# (Airbyte) MySQL to Snowflake error: connection was unexpectedly lost

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airbyte

I'm using airbyte to transfer data from MySQL database to Snowflake Database. Airbyte is deploy on EC2 t2.medium (CPU usage is between 60 to 70%) with 16GB storage capacity. When the airbyte connection is use to sync only a few table it's working fine but when I add all them I have this error.

`Nested Stack Trace: ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.io.EOFException MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 1,843 bytes, read 841 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost`

In the same time I have succes logs for all my table, like this :

```
2023-08-08 16:10:25 [42mnormalization[0m > 184 of 201 START table model <snowflake_schema>.<table_name>..................................................... [RUN]
2023-08-08 16:10:26 [42mnormalization[0m > 180 of 201 OK created table model <snowflake_schema>.<table_name>........................................................ [[32mSUCCESS 1[0m in 1.86s]
```

Airbyte get the data from MySQL a certain amount of time then stop :

```
2023-08-08 15:56:31 [44msource[0m > INFO i.a.d.j.s.AdaptiveStreamingQueryConfig(accept):40 Set new fetch size: 138428 rows
2023-08-08 15:56:31 [44msource[0m > INFO i.a.d.j.s.AdaptiveStreamingQueryConfig(accept):40 Set new fetch size: 137718 rows
2023-08-08 15:56:31 [44msource[0m > ERROR i.a.d.j.StreamingJdbcDatabase$1(tryAdvance):107 SQLState: S1000, Message: Error retrieving record: Unexpected Exception: java.io.EOFException message given: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 1,876 bytes, read 735 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

Comment: all servers have timeouts, so if you can change it increase it, or you need to have lless time consuming queries

Comment: change the timeouts on airbyte or mysql ? (or both)

Comment: Additional DB information request, please - from MySQL srvr. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.